# For loop return only last element using angular 2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular

I am using angular 2 with mongoDb. I am using service for called API.

Here is my example code:

`this.at` is just token like this `fdfdsfdffsdf...`

It's authorization key.

```
this.flatService.getFlats(this.at).subscribe(res: Response) => {
    for (var i in res) {
        console.log("i",i);
        var id=res[i].USER_ID;
        this.userService.getUserDetails(this.at,id).subscribe(users => {
            this.flatsdetails.push(user);
        });
    }  
});
```

First, I called `getFlats()`. It returned JSON values. The values have a USER_ID attribute. It's passed to another function in `getUserDetails()`.

I consoled the id values: like this 123, 234. `getUserDetails()` returns also Users JSON, after I pushed another array.

The user value looks like this: anitha, Ganesan.

I consoled the flatsdetails. It shows ['anitha','Ganesan'].

But the `i` values return only last element. Why?

```
USER_ID -> USERNAME
124     -> anitha
124     -> Ganesan
```

I need output like this:

```
  USER_ID -> USERNAME
    123     -> anitha
    124     -> Ganesan
```

also i tried to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
}
```

But I am not able to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post the `JSON` structure ?

Comment: Thanks for ur response.No i passed only id like this (234).

Comment: @vaishuani The JSON response that you receive after calling `.getFlats(this.at)` please post full structure.
@Alexandru-IonutMihai both `var` and `let` are viable that's not the cause of his problem

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović.I am using mongodb this.at is token.I update my code.Kindly check it.If i get result from API Just i passed authorization key.

Comment: You still don't understand me, I'm asking for `JSON RESPONSE` the value of `res` which is the response you get `AFTER` calling the database .... `this.flatService.getFlats(this.at).subscribe(res: Response) => { }` post `res`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For loop is not `asynchronous` so make it `forEach`

```
this.flatService.getFlats(this.at).subscribe(res: Response) => {
        angular.forEach(res, function(user, key) {
            console.log("i",i);
            var id=user.USER_ID;
            this.userService.getUserDetails(this.at,id).subscribe(users => {
                this.flatsdetails.push(user);
            });
        });  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur ans.I am getting this err  Cannot read property 'userService' of undefined.

Comment: changed regarding to your comment. you can also use `angular.forEach` @vaishuani

Comment: @phaniindra `.forEach` is not `asynchronous` either

Comment: Pleasure to help you